# Why is the selector being used by html outside of what i selected

Tags: html, css

Hi the selectors i included selects other elements that is not in the class i selected can someone explain why this is happening.Here the code....notice how i put a p tag outside the class and it still selects it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.one_one  h1, p{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:pink;
    width:100px;

}
.one_two h1, p{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
}
.one_three h1, p{
    background-color:orange;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;


}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="webdesign_info">
            <section class="one_one">
                    <h1>A wide variety of choices</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                           sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                           magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            </section>

            <section class="one_two">
                    <h1>Easy to search Through</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                           sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                           magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            </section>

            <section class="one_three">
                    <h1>1170px wide content area</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                           sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                           magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            <section>




        </div>
<p>Chrisk is sm</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The comma in a CSS selector separates multiple selectors that have the same styles. So, your CSS

```
.one_three h1, p
```

Is read by the browser like:

```
apply following styles to all (<h1>) in all of class (one_three), as well as all (<p>)
```

Which results in the `<p>`'s being styled by  last style in the stylesheet that selects the p(`.one_three h1, p` in this case)

In response to your comment, you would select the `<p>` and `<h1>` in `.one_three` like this:

```
.one_three h1, .one_three p
```

Which is read by the browser like:

```
apply following styles to all (<h1>) in all of class (one_three), as well as all (<p>) in all of class (one_three)
```

If you want a shorter to type version, you could use SCSS:

```
.one_three{
  h1, p{
    //Styles
  }
}
```

But, when compiled, that would output the same CSS as posted above, it is just easier to read and keep track of in development

Comment: so what can i do to select both the h1 and p tag only in this class....one_three h1 p..doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have the comma (,) before the p tag:

```
.one_one  h1, p
```

Please remove the comma and it will select the `p` tag inside the `h1` tag inside the `.one_one div`.